# Multiple passwordStorageScheme values on same user on 389ds / FreeIPA

Tags: redhat, ldap, freeipa, 389-ds

I have deployed a FreeIPA identity solution which is backed inside by a 389 directory server.

Due to the need of periodically syncing user passwords to another platform (Google Apps for Work), I need the user account storage schemes to be SHA1 instead of SSHA (salted SHA).

I could easily switch the passwordStorageScheme to SHA, but I don't know if IPA relies on the password being SSHA and I would break something, so:

- Can I 'happily' switch from SSHA to SHA passwordStorageScheme withouth breaking anything?
- Instead of that, can I configure 389 to save an additional hash in a custom attribute (lets say, 'userPasswordSHA'), each time a password changes, so I can easily dispose of both?

Comment: Just to note, FreIPA is backed by 389ds not because I've chosen it, but because it is the backend FreIPA uses. Not that I hate it or something, but I felt my phrasing was indicating it was my choice. And, as always, mind my lousy english.